# Relation between rank-2 antisymmetric tensor and other bilinear covariants

Tags: field-theory, tensor-calculus, dirac-equation, spinors, covariance

Given a spinor $\psi$, if one defines the bilinear covariants $J=\bar{\psi} \psi$,
$J_{5}=i \bar{\psi} \gamma_{5} \psi$, the current $J_{\mu}=i \bar{\psi} \gamma_{\mu} \psi$, the axial current $J_{5 \mu}=i \bar{\psi} \gamma_{5} \gamma_{\mu} \psi$, and the rank 2 antisymmetric tensor
\begin{aligned}
J_{\mu v}=\bar{\psi} \sigma_{\mu \nu} \psi
\end{aligned}
as per usual (here $\bar{\psi}$ is the adjoint spinor) it turns out that $J_{\mu v}$ can be written as
\begin{aligned}
J_{\mu v}=\frac{1}{J_{\alpha} J^{\alpha}}\left(J_{5}(J_{\mu} J_{5 v}-J_{v} J_{5 \mu})-i J \epsilon_{\mu v \alpha \beta} J_{\alpha} J_{5 \beta}\right)
\end{aligned}
This ultimately follows from the Fierz identities. However, this formula cannot be applied if the current is light-like (in this case one has $J_{\alpha} J^{\alpha}=0$ in the denominator). So I question is there a similar formula that relates $J_{\mu}$, $J_{5\mu}$, and $J_{\mu\nu}$ in the non-regular case $J=J_5=0$ (in which one thus has that $J_{\alpha} J^{\alpha}=J_{5\alpha} J^{5\alpha}=0$)? Any help will be much appreciated, it doesn't have to be a full answer if someone could just point me in some direction or give a reference, that would be more than enough.